# Is there an update for ag-gird to run with Chrome V74?

Tags: google-chrome, ag-grid

The latest version of Chrome V74 breaks ag-gird and it no longer displays.  Is there a patch of ag-grid which allows it to run in chrome?  Or, a setting in Chrome which allows ag-grid to display?

Comment: Not sure if this is a question or should be a new issues with the ag-grid project.

Comment: https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues may be a better place. But, it is very much doubtful that ag-grid is broken in Chrome 74. Anyway it works for me.

Comment: What version of ag-grid are you using? Exactly what version of Chrome are you using (such as: Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit))? Does it work in incognito mode? Does the [official demo](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/) work for you? If the demo works but your page doesn't the problem is with your page and you haven't shown any code, so we can't help you. Are there any errors in your browser console? You need to do some basic debugging here! It all seems to work for me.

Comment: the official demo does work .. so it must be something on the page